# nvim use defx instead of NerdTree

Tags: plugins, neovim, nerdtree

I would like to open nvim with defx by default instead of Nerdtree. Have no idea how to change that behaviour

I am using defx and can open it through mapping with  **sf** custom mapping command, but for that i should be already in nvim so it takes me  two steps.

```sh
vim 
sf
```

Sf lives in maps.vim

```sh
" Description: Keymaps
" defx
nnoremap <silent>sf :<C-u>Defx -listed -resume
      \ -columns=indent:mark:icon:icons:filename:git:size
      \ -buffer-name=tab`tabpagenr()`
      \ `expand('%:p:h')` -search=`expand('%:p')`<CR>
```

Can i open defx with

```sh
nvim .
```

I can disable nerdtree from opening in nvim/init.vim

```sh
 " Disable netrw
 let g:loaded_netrwPlugin       = 1
```

but even with it I should do **sf** to open defx

Comment: can you pls show your `sf` mapping? I don't use this plugin, so I want to see the command to trigger it.

Comment: nnoremap <silent>sf :<C-u>Defx -listed -resume
      \ -columns=indent:mark:icon:icons:filename:git:size
      \ -buffer-name=tab`tabpagenr()`
      \ `expand('%:p:h')` -search=`expand('%:p')`<CR>

Answer (score 0):

so the answer from creator @Shougo  was
https://gitter.im/Shougo/defx.nvim?at=61abfda5b5ba9e5a11ef079e

```sh
autocmd BufEnter,VimEnter,BufNew,BufWinEnter,BufRead,BufCreate
          \ * if isdirectory(expand('<amatch>'))
          \   | call s:browse_check(expand('<amatch>')) | endif

    function! s:browse_check(path) abort
      if bufnr('%') != expand('<abuf>')
        return
      endif

      " Disable netrw.
      augroup FileExplorer
        autocmd!
      augroup END

      execute 'Defx' a:path
    endfunction
```